# Regex matching every character until a certain character ONLY if that certain character exists

Tags: java, regex, wikipedia-api

Basically, I'm reading information from the Wikipedia API, which returns JSON code containing the source code for a page in their markdown. I used a JSON API to filter what I want from the page, and now I want to format the text in a way that removes all the links and such.

The markdown displays links like this: `[[wiki page|display text]]`
But it can also display like this: `[[wiki page]]`

So, what I'm trying to do is extract the `display text` if the pipe character exists, but if not I just want the `wiki page` text.

This is my code for that right now, which *should* detect if there's a pipe character and handle those strings properly but doesn't:

```
private static String format(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\[\\[.+?(\\]\\]|\\|)", "").replace("[[", "").replace("]]", "").trim();
}
```

When running this it will sometimes take out any text that displays as simply `[[wiki page]]`, but it works if the pipe character is there. How do I manage to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
private static String format(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\[\\[(?:[^|\\]]*\\|)?(.+?)\\]\\]", "$1");
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC3rT8/2)

Comment: This works great! However, when passed in `[[wiki page]] [[wiki page|display text]]`, only `display text` is given back. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
((?<=\\[\\[)[^|]*|(?<=\\|).*?)(?=\\]\\])
```

You can use this.Grab the `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/2